Using systemd to sleep computer for x seconds?
How can I send a machine to sleep/hibernate for a dynamical amount of seconds and have it automatically wake up after that time?
For now I have the following script, which I kinda hacked together:
#!/bin/bash
systemd-run --unit='WakeTimer' --on-active=${1}s  --timer-property='AccuracySec=1s' --timer-property='WakeSystem=true' ;systemctl suspend

I can call the above script with an argument and send my linux machine to sleep with for a number of seconds. It seems to work, but I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to do it?
Also this only suspends the machine as far as I understand, and I'm wondering whether there is a deeper sleep I can get the machine to enter, since I only want it to wake up once a week automatically anyway and otherwise I want it to use as little power as possible.

Can you please [edit] and clarify what you are asking? What is the actual question here? Why do you have this /bin/sh -c "date"? What is it you want to achieve with that? What part of this do you not understand? Where do you need help?

sorry the question was a bit of a mess, I tried to remove the /bin/sh -c "date" part earlier but it somehow seemed to break the script back then so I left it in, but now I tried again and it seems to run fine without so I just removed it. I also tried to make my question clearer.
